# Problems with Compass/Sass

Tags: java, ruby, macos, compass-sass

I'm having some problems regarding Compass an Sass.

I just installed Compass on my Mac with there Terminal (without using sudo). After that I install Compass.App. I have a local file folder with an omega them (from drupal) in it. When I try to watch the folder I get the following error:

```
no such file to load -- rgbapng
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1065:in `require'
file:/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Java/lib/java/jruby-complete.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
file:/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Java/lib/java/jruby-complete.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require'
file:/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Java/compass-app.jar!/require_patch.rb:6:in `require'
/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/lib/ruby/compass_1.0/compass-core-1.0.0/lib/compass/configuration/data.rb:179:in `require'
/Users/Julia/Documents/pompon/neues Web/Design/pompon/config.rb:26:in `parse_string'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1101:in `eval'
/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/lib/ruby/compass_1.0/compass-1.0.0/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:24:in `parse_string'
/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/lib/ruby/compass_1.0/compass-1.0.0/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:15:in `_parse'
org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1181:in `open'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:349:in `open'
file:/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Java/lib/java/jruby-complete.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.9/open-uri.rb:35:in `open'
/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/lib/ruby/compass_1.0/compass-1.0.0/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:14:in `_parse'
/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/lib/ruby/compass_1.0/compass-1.0.0/lib/compass/configuration/file_data.rb:7:in `new_from_file'
/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/lib/ruby/compass_1.0/compass-core-1.0.0/lib/compass/configuration/inheritance.rb:207:in `with_defaults'
/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/lib/ruby/compass_1.0/compass-1.0.0/lib/compass/configuration/file_data.rb:6:in `new_from_file'
/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/lib/ruby/compass_1.0/compass-1.0.0/lib/compass/configuration/helpers.rb:19:in `configuration_for'
/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/lib/ruby/compass_1.0/compass-1.0.0/lib/compass/configuration/helpers.rb:69:in `add_project_configuration'
/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/lib/ruby/compass_1.0/compass-1.0.0/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:37:in `add_project_configuration'
/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/lib/ruby/compass_1.0/compass-1.0.0/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:25:in `configure!'
/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/lib/ruby/compass_1.0/compass-1.0.0/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:15:in `initialize'
/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Resources/lib/ruby/compass_1.0/compass-1.0.0/lib/compass/commands/update_project.rb:41:in `initialize'
file:/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Java/compass-app.jar!/ui/tray.rb:431:in `watch'
file:/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Java/compass-app.jar!/app.rb:230:in `try'
file:/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Java/compass-app.jar!/ui/tray.rb:424:in `watch'
file:/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Java/compass-app.jar!/ui/tray.rb:178:in `open_dir_handler'
anon_class786058987_1935698467.gen:13:in `handleEvent'
file:/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Java/compass-app.jar!/ui/tray.rb:70:in `run'
file:/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Java/compass-app.jar!/main.rb:129:in `run_tray'
file:/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Java/compass-app.jar!/main.rb:145:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1065:in `require'
file:/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Java/lib/java/jruby-complete.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1:in `(root)'
file:/Applications/compass.app/Contents/Java/lib/java/jruby-complete.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

I already tried `compass compile` in the terminal (as suggested in another question). The answer is `-bash: compass: command not found`.

I just did a new setup of my Mac. So everything is fresh installed.

So any help is welcome!

Best regards, Julia

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Ruby installed on your machine for Compass to work. But if u want things to be easy, check **[Scout](http://mhs.github.io/scout-app/)**. This one doesn't need Ruby, it will run in it's own sandbox. It's a bit slow at start-up but after that everything works smoothly.
You can refer to this [link](http://www.impressivewebs.com/sass-on-windows-with-scout-app/) for more info

Comment: Ruby is installed as it is installed on every mac `$  ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]`. I tried scout before, but I can't get it working Scout gives me this output `No Java runtime present, requesting install.`, even after installing the latest version of java.

Comment: if u already installed java, add that path as a new environment variable.. JAVA_HOME=/path-to-ur-jdk